# Paginate without a gem Next, Previous, buttons for Name.order(:id).limit(10).offset(0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination

I've been searching for a solution to my problem for over a week now. I have an assignment that I lost 10 pts on due to no next/prev functionality and ran out of time. I still want to figure this out though.

I have Created a short single page site with `rails generate scaffold Ripple name:string message:text url:string` that shows an index of 10 most recent posts displays (name, message, created_on, link_to "show"). I still have to create a next, previous, newest, oldest links in view to show next 10, prev 10.... results. My code.

`app\controllers\ripple_controller.rb`

```
class RipplesController < ApplicationController  
  before_action :set_ripple, only: [:show, :update]  
  before_action :restrict_destroy_edit, only: [:edit, :destroy]   
  before_filter :set_page   
  helper_method :link_name_to_url, :next_button, :previous_button, :newest_button, :oldest_button, :is_next_page_available, :is_previous_page_available

  RIPPLES_PER_PAGE = 10

  def index   
    @ripples = Ripple.order(:id).limit(RIPPLES_PER_PAGE).offset(@page * RIPPLES_PER_PAGE) 
  end
  #All my show, new, destroy, edit, create ....

  def next_button

  end

  def previous_button

  end

  def newest_button

  end

  def oldest_button

  end

  def is_next_page_available?

  end

  def is_previous_page_available?

  end

  def set_page 
    @page = 5 
  end
private
...
```

`\app\views\ripples.html.erb`

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Message</th>
      <th>Posted</th>
      <th>Show Ripple</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @ripples.each do |ripple| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_name_to_url ripple %></td>
        <td><%= truncate(ripple.message, length: 50) %></td>
        <td><%= ripple.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y %l:%M %P") %></td>
        <td><%= button_to 'Show', ripple, :method => "get" %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<div id = "nav">
  <button><%= link_to 'Newest' %></button>
  <button><%= link_to 'Previous 10 Ripples' %></button>
  <button><%= link_to "Next 10 Ripples" %></button>
  <button><%= link_to 'Oldest' %></button>
  <button><%= link_to 'New Ripple', new_ripple_path, class: "button", method: :get %></button>
</div>
```

And I've tried calling methods in Model but keep getting `undefined method "next" for #<Class:0xb4eabd0c>` error on next and previous.

`app\models\ripple.rb`

```
class Ripple < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope -> {order(created_at: :desc)}
  validates :name, :message, presence: true
  validates :url, allow_blank: true, format: {
  with: URI::regexp(%w(http https)),
      message: "Must be a url starting with http:// or https://"
  }

  def next
    Ripple.order(:id).limit(10).offset((@page - 1) * 10)
  end

  def previous
    Ripple.order(:id).limit(10).offset((@page + 1) * 10)
  end
end
```

How would I implement next and previous using the order().limit().offset and maybe use `@page` to keep track of where I'm at in the ActiveRecord. Maybe something like

```
def next_button
  @page -= 1
end
```

that I can call in index `"<%= link_to Next 10" next_button %>` either way I'm out of ideas that might work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a gem? If so [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) does everything for you, if not take a peek at its source code.

Comment: `undefined method "next" for #<Class:0xb4eabd0c> error on next and previous` this error you are getting because you are trying to call `instance method's` on class. To make next and previous methods available at class level you need to add `self` before those methods. i.e. `def self.next` and `def self.previous`

Comment: I wish I could have, I know how to use will-paginate. But no I have to write it myself, though I did get a hint today, use session[:page] instead of @page. Apparently rails won't communicate ruby variables between view and controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things here. Firstly, controller methods should be used with matching routes. It's a request cycle where you click a button on your app, it makes a request to your server, then your server response with information.

Your `next_button` method is not going to work when you put it as a `helper_method` this way. In order to make your controller work, you should have routes that match to your controller method. Do a `rake routes` in your command line. You need to see something like this in your `route.rb` file

```
get 'ripple/next', 'ripple#next'
```

More about `routes`: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

And in your controller, you could have

```
def next
  page = params[:page]
  params[:page] += 1
  @ripples = Ripple.find_ripples_on_page(page, PAGE_SIZE)
  render :index
end
```

Then in your erb view, your should be 'visiting' this particular route, not calling the method.

Secondly, you can not rely on class instance variable in your model. Instead, you should put it in your session or as part of a query string. As above controller code, I put it in session, which is a local storage. More about `session`: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session

Finally, your model.

```
def find_ripples_on_page(page, PAGE_SIZE)
  Ripple.where( ... ) # you can figure this out, depending on if you want to rank by updated_at or other filter
end
```

**Side note**: `helper_method` in controller is for retrieving information not giving command to the controller. All this macro does is use `class_eval` and 'copy' the method you have in controller into the `renderer`.

**If you can use a gem, use `will_paginate`.**

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. I learned more in this block than I did in the whole book I've been reading. This has helped me out a lot, as this was my first project in rails/ first time using Ruby and I've been using java and c# so far. Awesome learning experience though. I'll implement this tomorrow after work and see what happens. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
class RipplesController < ApplicationController  
  before_filter :set_page, only: [:index]
  RIPPLES_PER_PAGE = 10
  def index   
    @ripples = Ripple.order(:id).limit(RIPPLES_PER_PAGE).offset(@page * RIPPLES_PER_PAGE) 
  end
  private
    def set_page
       @page = params[:page].to_i || 0
    end
end
```

Then in the view links will be

```
<div id = "nav">
    <button><%= link_to 'Newest', ripples_path %></button>
    <button><%= link_to 'Previous 10 Ripples', ripples_path(page: @page - 1) %></button>
    <button><%= link_to "Next 10 Ripples", ripples_path(page: @page + 1) %></button>
</div>
```

All of this will be driven through the `RipplesController#index` method and will use URL's like `/ripples?page=1`, `/ripples?page=2`, etc.

These `link_to` calls will generate links with `GET` variables so that you can access them in the `params` hash and use them to drive the results returned.

Comment: This is awesome, this has pointed out a few things to me about rails that I didn't know. For one I should quit treating it like java. Thank you for this @engineersmnky.

Comment: getting "No Implicit Conversion of Integer into String" in the link_to using this method. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @ncarroll try `@page = params[:page].to_i || 0` in `set_page`