# Paginating with only next button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

I am trying to make next button which should show only one record per page. I know we can use pagination but I only want to have Next button. So, I read the following post and implemented it:
My **questions** controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_page, only: [:view]
  QUESTIONS_PER_PAGE = 1
  def view
    questions=[]
    @evaluation = Evaluation.pluck(:content).last
    @evaluation.each do |question|
      questions << question
    end
    @questions=Question.where(:content => questions).limit(QUESTIONS_PER_PAGE).offset(@page*QUESTIONS_PER_PAGE)
    #@questions=Question.where(:content => questions).paginate(page: params[:page],per_page: 1)
  end
  private
    def set_page
       @page = params[:page] || 0
    end
```

**My view.html.erb** which gives error: no implicit conversion of Integer into String

```
<h1>Self-Evaluation Exam</h1>

<table id="questions">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Content &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @questions.each do |question| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= question.content %></td>
            <td><%= check_box_tag question.c1 %></td>
            <td><%= question.c1%></td>
            <td><%= check_box_tag question.c2 %></td>
            <td><%= question.c2%></td>
            <td><%= check_box_tag question.c3 %></td>
            <td><%= question.c3%></td>
            <td><%= check_box_tag question.c4 %></td>
            <td><%= question.c4%></td>
            <td><%= check_box_tag question.c5 %></td>
            <td><%= question.c5%></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id = "nav">
    <%= button_to 'Next',questions_path(page: @page + 1) %># this line gives error: no implicit conversion of Integer into String
</div>
<li><%= link_to 'Personal Evaluation',instructions_student_path %></li>
```

[Paginate without a gem Next, Previous, buttons for Name.order(:id).limit(10).offset(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070685/paginate-without-a-gem-next-previous-buttons-for-name-orderid-limit10-off)
It shows the first page but then when I click on the button I get the error
PS: the next button should be changed to Submit when its on the last record
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple, try to the following

```
QUESTIONS_PER_PAGE = 1
@questions = Question.where(content: questions).offset(QUESTIONS_PER_PAGE * @page).limit(QUESTIONS_PER_PAGE)

private
def set_page
   @page = (params[:page] || 0).to_i
end
```

change to your `view.html.erb` with `next >>` and `<< previous`

```
<div id="nav">
    <nav>
        <ul class="pager">
            <li class="previous <%= @page == 0 ? 'disabled' : '' %>">
                <%= link_to_if page > 0, "&larr; Previous".html_safe, questions_path(page: @page - 1) %>
            </li>
            <li class="next">
                <%= link_to "Next &rarr;".html_safe, questions_path(page: @page + 1) %>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

So your `controller` look like this

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_page, only: [:view]
    QUESTIONS_PER_PAGE = 1
    def view
        questions=[]
        @evaluation = Evaluation.pluck(:content).last
        @evaluation.each do |question|
          questions << question
        end
        @questions = Question.where(content: questions).offset(QUESTIONS_PER_PAGE * @page).limit(QUESTIONS_PER_PAGE)
    end

    private
    def set_page
       @page = (params[:page] || 0).to_i
    end
end
```

if you need to only next button to your view then use only

```
<%= link_to "Next &rarr;".html_safe, questions_path(page: @page + 1) %>
```

With condition

```
<% if @page == @questions.count %>
    <button>Finished</button>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Next &rarr;".html_safe, questions_path(page: @page + 1) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You are Welcome

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the url builder is failing because it's trying to convert an integer to a string. Also, incrementing a value is += typically.

I'm betting that params[:page] is returning a string instead of an integer. What happens if you do `@page.to_i += 1`? Something along those lines will at least get you past this initial error.

Comment: I changed it in my controller to `params[:page].to_i`. However, now I am having the next button forever. I want to stop it when I am on the last record and the button should be submit instead. Can you please help in that?